# DataAnnotationsExtensions with Visual Basic in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I might actually be going insane, but I can't find a single example of how to use DataAnnotationsExtensions with Visual Basic in MVC 3.  I'm tired of guessing.

Anyone one want to point me to an example or provide some simple code to show me how to use the tags?

Thank you!!

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Simply try to understand the syntax.  i tried mimicking the regular data annotation syntax but I have trouble for instance validating dates. I got the regular data annotation working.  I can't believe I am the only person that is doing this stuff in VB or maybe I'm just dense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's pretty straightforward actually.

1. You create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application
2. You install the [DataAnnotationsExtensions.MVC3](http://nuget.org/packages/DataAnnotationsExtensions.MVC3) Nuget
3. You create a view model:

   ```
   Public Class MyViewModel
       <CreditCard(ErrorMessage:="Invalid credit card number")>
       Public Property Number As String
   End Class
   ```
4. A controller:

   ```
   Public Class HomeController
       Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

       Function Index() As ActionResult
           Return View(New MyViewModel())
       End Function

       <HttpPost()>
       Function Index(ByVal model As MyViewModel) As ActionResult
           Return View(model)
       End Function
   End Class
   ```
5. And finally a view:

   ```
   @ModelType AppName.MyViewModel

   @Using Html.BeginForm()
       @Html.LabelFor(Function(x) x.Number)
       @Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.Number)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(x) x.Number)
       @<button type="submit">OK</button>
   End Using
   ```

Comment: Excellent, that much is clear.  Can you show me an example with things like error messages and other attributes?
I'm concerned mainly with the model end of things.

Comment: Sure, I have updated my example to illustrate how you could specify an error message. As far as the other attributes are concerned I invite you to read the documentation: http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2011/02/23/introducing-data-annotations-extensions.aspx. And if you have troubles with the VB.NET syntax, well, I invite you to read VB.NET tutorials.

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, but the syntax is essentially the same as normal data annotations?

Comment: What syntax are you talking about? Data Annotations are simple .NET attributes so the syntax is the same as all .NET attributes.

Comment: That was the magic words I was in search of.  Thanks, you have been most helpful!!